Recursively check each test case project/CR Id field value for consistency
In Azure DevOps, I am trying to get project/CR Id field's value recursively from each user story and all its child items -> test cases at any level and match each test case's project/CR Id field's value for consistency, if they are present and same. I am getting the below error using SDK.
import os
import operator as op
import re
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication

# Replace with your actual PAT and organization URL
personal_access_token = 'PAT'
organization_url = 'https://dev.azure.com/**'
work_item_id = 123  # Replace with your actual work item ID

# Create connection to the organization
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

# Get work item tracking client for interacting with work items API.
work_item_tracking_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()

def check_project_cr_ids_consistency(work_item):
    project_cr_ids_consistent = True
    project_cr_id_value = None
    
    def recursive_check(item):
        nonlocal project_cr_ids_consistent, project_cr_id_value
        
        if 'Custom.ProjectorCRId' in item.fields:
            current_project_cr_id_value = item.fields['Custom.ProjectorCRId']
            
            if current_project_cr_id_value.strip() == "":
                project_cr_ids_consistent = False

            elif project_cr_id_value is None:
                project_cr_id_value = current_project_cr_id_value

            elif project_cr_id_value != current_project_cr_id_value:
                project_cr_ids_consistent = False
        
        else:
            project_cr_ids_consistent = False
        
        if hasattr(item, 'relations'):
            for relation in item.relations:
                if relation.rel == 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward':
                    child_id = int(relation.url.split('/')[-1])
                    child_work_items = work_item_tracking_client.get_work_items(ids=[child_id])
                    
                    for child_work_item in child_work_items:
                        recursive_check(child_work_item)
    
    recursive_check(work_item)
    
    return (project_cr_ids_consistent, project_cr_id_value)

try:
    # Fetch details of the specific work item by ID, including relations (child items).
    work_item = work_item_tracking_client.get_work_item(id=work_item_id, expand='all')
    
    # Print details of the fetched work item.
    title=work_item.fields['System.Title']
    print(f"Title: {title}")
   
    consistent , cr_or_project_value= check_project_cr_ids_consistency(work_item) 

except Exception as e :
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

print(f"Project/CR IDs Consistent: {consistent}")
if not consistent :
    print("Inconsistent Project/CR IDs found among children.")
else :
   print(f"Consistent Project/CR ID Value: {cr_or_project_value}")

pattern=re.compile(r'\b' + re.escape(cr_or_project_value) + r'\b')

match=pattern.search(title)

print(bool(match))

Error:
An error occurred: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'consistent' is not defined
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\CRAutomation\projectid.py", line 67, in <module>
    print(f"Project/CR IDs Consistent: {consistent}")
NameError: name 'consistent' is not defined

Complete Error:-
PS C:\Users\Desktop\CRAutomation>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\Desktop\repo\CR_Devops_Automate'; & 'c:\Python310\python.exe' 'c:\Users\703301396\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '55082' '--' 'C:\Users\703301396\Desktop\CRAutomation\projectid.py' 

Title: test 123
An error occurred: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>   
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "c:\Users\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "c:\Users\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\CRAutomation\projectid.py", line 67, in <module>
    print(f"Project/CR IDs Consistent: {consistent}")
NameError: name 'consistent' is not defined

After removing try except:-
PS C:\Users\Desktop\repo\CR_Devops_Automate>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\Desktop\repo\CR_Devops_Automate'; & 'c:\Python310\python.exe' 'c:\Users\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '56267' '--' 'C:\Users\703301396\Desktop\CRAutomation\projectid.py' 
Title: test 123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\703301396\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>   
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\Users\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "c:\Users\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "c:\Users\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.10.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\CRAutomation\projectid.py", line 62, in <module>
    consistent = cr_or_project_value= check_project_cr_ids_consistency(work_item)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\CRAutomation\projectid.py", line 50, in check_project_cr_ids_consistency
    recursive_check(work_item)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\CRAutomation\projectid.py", line 48, in recursive_check
    recursive_check(child_work_item)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\CRAutomation\projectid.py", line 42, in recursive_check
    for relation in item.relations:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable


consistent is not defined by check_project_cr_ids_consistency, you need to check the error raised in the try block.

An error occurred: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

This is not enough information. You need to post the full stack trace of this error or just debug your script to see where you are trying to iterate over None.

Updated above with complete error.

This is the wrong stacktrace, you are hiding the first error 'NoneType' object is not iterable by catching the exception. Remove the try-except to see the full stacktrace.

Added error after removing try-except

item.relations is None. Why it's None depends on your data.

This happens because error occurs in your try/except block and consistent was never initialised. Just put code, related to consistent inside of try/except block:
try:
    # Fetch details of the specific work item by ID, including relations (child items).
    work_item = work_item_tracking_client.get_work_item(id=work_item_id, expand='all')
    
    # Print details of the fetched work item.
    title=work_item.fields['System.Title']
    print(f"Title: {title}")
   
    consistent , cr_or_project_value= check_project_cr_ids_consistency(work_item)

    print(f"Project/CR IDs Consistent: {consistent}")
    if not consistent :
        print("Inconsistent Project/CR IDs found among children.")
    else:
       print(f"Consistent Project/CR ID Value: {cr_or_project_value}")
    pattern=re.compile(r'\b' + re.escape(cr_or_project_value) + r'\b')
    match=pattern.search(title)
    print(bool(match))

except Exception as e :
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")


Or initialise this variables as None outside of try except block:
consistent, cr_or_project_value = None, None
try:
    # Fetch details of the specific work item by ID, including relations (child items).
    work_item = work_item_tracking_client.get_work_item(id=work_item_id, expand='all')
    
    # Print details of the fetched work item.
    title=work_item.fields['System.Title']
    print(f"Title: {title}")
   
    consistent , cr_or_project_value= check_project_cr_ids_consistency(work_item) 

except Exception as e :
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

print(f"Project/CR IDs Consistent: {consistent}")
if not consistent :
    print("Inconsistent Project/CR IDs found among children.")
elif cr_or_project_value:
    print(f"Consistent Project/CR ID Value: {cr_or_project_value}")
    pattern=re.compile(r'\b' + re.escape(cr_or_project_value) + r'\b')
    match=pattern.search(title)
    print(bool(match))


This error also exist which I missed: An error occurred: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Could you provide please, which line raises this error?

Updated above with complete error
